# Clear browser Cookies with Selenium WebDriver Java bindings

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know if it's possible to Clear Browser Cookies for WebDriver before starting the automation? (Note: Not Selenium RC)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it's possible

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Call it right after you are creating the new WebDriver instance.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

You can also delete the cookies one by one

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : allCookies) {
    driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed(cookie.getName());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete the cookies from another(cross) domain?

Comment: note:  by default, new WebDriver instances start with a fresh profile and no cookies

Comment: @PranavBilurkar for ChromeDriver - yes, see my answer.

Comment: _Call it right after you are creating the new WebDriver instance._ - can you use it in the middle of a run? And can you remove all cookies for a specific domain while letting the others remain untouched?

Answer (score 10):

Does this work for you?

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Answer (score 3):

`ChromeDriver` provides a way to clear cookies of **all** websites/domains:

```cs
driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Storage.clearCookies", new Dictionary<string, object>())
```