# clearing cache on chrome using web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

We are testing web app using Jmeter selenium webdriver.
as HTTP manager doenst work we were trying to clear the cache using below Code. Due to some reason this is failling. We need clear cache mechanism to be implemented. Besides this we also tried incognito mode many other options as gooogle suggests without luck. 
We are also trying to hit (Sendkeys) Enter after lauching browser as (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData) it on clear browsing window. Driver.close() will not help us as per the scenario needs.

Please throw some ideas / suggest how to execute Enter after browser launch.

Really appreciate your time and help.

```
    var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium,org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) //import java selenium packages
var Thr=JavaImporter(java.lang.Thread) //import Thread sleep packages
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,30) //import WebDriverWait Package
WDS.browser.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
Thr.Thread.sleep(5000)
WDS.browser.switchTo().frame("settings")
var ChkBox = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="delete-form-data-checkbox"]'))
ChkBox.click()
////*[@id="clear-browser-data-overlay"]/div[4]
//wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="clear-browser-data-commit"]')))
//wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="clear-browser-data-overlay"]/div[4]')))
var ClearCache = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="clear-browser-data-commit"]'))
ClearCache.click()
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="privacy-section"]/h3')))
```

Comment: It looks like you have already cleared the cache on your browser. If you did and that didn't fix it, then it's not the cache that's the issue. Something in your code needs work. I don't know very much about selenium, so this is a shot in the dark, but do you need to wrap `Thr.Thread.sleep(5000)` in a try catch statement?

Comment: wanderer0810, thanks for your quick reply. the above code use to work earlier and no more currently due to some changes of xpaths and frame. I would need a command to atleast click direct Enter on the active browser (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData) Post lauching the URL if you click enter it will clear the cache. But WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) is not working for some reason.

Comment: Thr.Thread.sleep(5000) is just explicit waiting time.

Comment: how did you obtain that xpath? looking at my chrome, I don't see frame "settings ", and nothing with `@id="delete-form-data-checkbox`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear browser Cookies with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403614/clear-browser-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Yeah that was the thing got changed. that frame settings is not recognized recently.

Comment: I am also trying the below without luck...any suggestions are greatly appreciated...
public WebDriver chromedriver
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--disable-cache")
driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
WDS.browser.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')

Comment: ignore that code...it is not working anymore..just gave it for reference as it was working earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The current chrome browser clear cache button is shadowed (its a ShadowDOM). We will not be able to interact with it directly. We will need to identify its JS path and perform the click using the executeScript function. No java packages need to be imported for the executeScript function.

Just append the below line for clearing the cache in your script.

```
WDS.browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#advancedPage > settings-section:nth-child(1) > settings-privacy-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog").shadowRoot.querySelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm").click();')
```

Happy testing using JMeter+WebDriver