# How to expire current session which expires after specific time early?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I make the selenium web driver to believe we already past specific time and the current session got expired?

Comment: What? You need to add some details as to what your scenario is and post the code you have written to attempt to accomplish this. Right now, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @JeffC, The scenario I'm trying to achieve is After login to the website if the user is idle for some amount of time the web page gives a popup for the user whether to continue the session or end the session. I want to validate this scenario. Is there any way we can trick the webdriver to think that time is already expired to show this popup without actually waiting for the entire time.

Comment: That makes more sense. Please edit your question and add all those details and any more you can think of to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to delete the cookie that holds the ID for the instance launched. I believe they are called session cookies.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the session expiry mechanism you're using. If you're relying on the browser to discard the session cookie, you can just [delete the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403614/clear-browser-cookies-with-selenium-webdriver-java-bindings). Note that if your application relies solely on the browser cookie expiry, your application is subject to session extension insufficient session expiration vulnerability. You should consider adding a server side expiration as well.

To test server side expiration, you can simulate expired session by altering the expiry date of the token in the server's database to have an expiration date in the past.

If you used a stateless timestamped and signed token for your session management, you can simulate expired token by issuing a token with a timestamp in the past. Note that using stateless timestamped and signed tokens will be subject to session expiration vulnerability, you should consider mitigating this risk by giving short expiry to the token.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before on one of our sites but it's not tricking WebDriver, it involved changing the JS on the page that controlled the timeouts to shorten the time waited. You will need to talk to dev or investigate the JS on the page to find out how/when the timeout is set. In my case, it involved rerunning a JS method with a different timeout value but your scenario will most assuredly be different and will involve some investigation and trial and error.